# Appengine clear expired session, but Admin permission is required to access https://[domain]/_ah/sessioncleanup?clear

Tags: google-app-engine, session

The project work in Appengine, and I want to clear the expired session, follow this doc : 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine-java/Tw2a8cYz05o/UgsWaoQhWYcJ

Web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>_ah_sessioncleanup</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.SessionCleanupServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>_ah_sessioncleanup</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/sessioncleanup</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Default page to serve -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>session-clean-up</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/_ah/sessioncleanup</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

cron.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
  <cron>
    <url>/_ah/sessioncleanup?clear</url>
    <description>Clean up sessions</description>
    <schedule>every 15 minutes</schedule>
  </cron>
</cronentries>
```

But the log show that :

09:55:00.957  GET  403  94 B  2 ms    AppEngine  /_ah/sessioncleanup?clear

Response 403

[image]

Anybody can help me? thanks.